# Scrolling till end of the listview in native android application using Appium in c#

Tags: c#, appium

I am using appium dotnet driver to automate native android application . I have the requirement to scroll down till the end of my listview to populate the next hidden objects . I have tried Touch action but it did not work. Please suggest how to scroll till the end of the application

Answer (score 0):

For the following to work, you need to know the text of the last item in your listview:

```
lvElement = driver.find_element(:class, 'android.widget.ListView')
scrollToItem = {}
scrollToItem["element"] = lvElement.ref
scrollToItem["text"]='{the text of the last item}'
```

Now use the 'scrollTo' command, which will scroll until it finds the text of the wanted item:

```
driver.execute_script("mobile: scrollTo", scrollToItem)
```

Comment: Thanks nissim , will let you know if this will work.

Comment: what is scrollToitem here. Is this the list or what . I am using c#

Comment: Hi I ma coding in c# using using appium dot net driver and automating native android application so please suggest acoording to that